# Installshield LE for VS2015 Professional after installing VS2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield-le

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional after having worked with Visual Studio 2015 Community for a few months.

The problem is that I cannot create a new Installshield Limited Edition project. I thought the issue was that I had both versions installed at the same time, but after removing VS Community, the issue still remains.

As you see in the screenshot below, the project type is located under a 1033 branch, which doesn't seem right to me. Creating a project only redirects me to the default HTML page, which tells me how to register and create a project.

I have uninstalled both versions and installed a fresh copy of VS2015 Professional from scratch. I didn't do any manual removal of certain files or caches, so maybe this could have something to do with it?

Anyone has experience with this? Perhaps any solution?

[image]

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and have yet to manage fixing it.

Comment: (A year later..)   I'm having the same issue with VS2015.  It just doesn't think that InstallShield has been installed, and redirects to the Download page.  Was this ever fixed ?

Comment: @MikeGledhill  Don't think so. I didn't bother and go with WiX.